# Display a pop up when youtube video ends

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, video, youtube

I need a pop up (facebook like share box) to be displayed when the the youtube video stops.
I already have lots of videos on my wordpress website. I need this to work for all my previous videos. 
I've already tried this from another post here:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>YT Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
      // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
      var tag = document.createElement('script');
      tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      // 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player) after the API code downloads.
      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '390',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'ecccag3L-yw',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      // The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
      function onPlayerReady(event) { /* do nothing yet */ }

      // The API calls this function when the player's state changes.

      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                // insert appropriate modal (or whatever) below
                alert('I hope you enjoyed the video')
        }
      }
      -->

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
</body>
<html>
```

isn't helping. This works only for one video. ecccag3L-yw in this case.
Can someone help me do this right?
here is an example of what I need. http://www.broascadilie.ro/index.php/video/item/29208-c%C3%A2nd-ea-are-chef-%C8%99i-tu-nu-when-she-is-in-the-mood-and-he-isnt
after the video ends, a pop up comes up for users to like and/or share.

Comment: If my answer helped you, mark it as best answer and thumb up!
If you post your database structure I may help you with the DB connection

Comment: I get "an error occurred" for all my videos. how do I make a database connection for this?

Comment: I found this snippet  preg_match('#<object[^>]+>.+?http://www.youtube.com/v/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+).+?</object>#s', $markup, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);. I use it for videoid but the alert won't work

Comment: Why don't you show me the page you are trying to display,

Comment: I would like to help you, but if you don't even know how to make a database connection I won't waste my time

Answer (score 0):

This one isn't hard. You need to change `videoId: 'ecccag3L-yw'` to `videoId: '<?php echo $id?>'`

Also you need to make sure that in the `$id` variable is stored your video ID. Since you are using wordpress you should just make a connection to the database and get the value you are interested.
So about after the `<title></title>`